# Core Plot bar graph - Bar does not show up

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, graph, core-plot

I have implemented a core plot bar graph as the following, it fires the data sources and taking the values. But the plot does not show up any bars. Can somebody tell me where is a the issue. I am just started using the CorePlot for Graphics.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)plotDataValues
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:4500123.213],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:12000500.213],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:10800456.213],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:7000500.213],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:5500300.213],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:3800623.213],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:2600345.213],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1900764.213],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:8600500.213],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1200376.213], nil];

    return array;
}



- (void)initTopPropertyPlot
{
    self.topWellsGraphHostingView.allowPinchScaling = NO;
    [self configurePropertyListGraph];
    [self configurePropertyPlot];
    [self configurePropertyPlotAxes];
}

- (void)configurePropertyListGraph
{
    //Create the Bar Graph.
    self.propertyListBarChart = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.topWellsGraphHostingView.bounds];
    self.propertyListBarChart.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
    self.topWellsGraphHostingView.hostedGraph = self.propertyListBarChart;

    // 2 - Configure the graph
    //[self.propertyListBarChart applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTSlateTheme]];
    [self.propertyListBarChart applyTheme:nil];
    self.propertyListBarChart.paddingBottom = 30.0f;
    self.propertyListBarChart.paddingLeft   = 50.0f;
    self.propertyListBarChart.paddingTop    = 20.0f;
    self.propertyListBarChart.paddingRight  = 0.0f;

    // 3 - Set up styles
    CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    titleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
    // 4 - Set up title
    NSString *title = @"";
    self.propertyListBarChart.title = title;
    self.propertyListBarChart.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
    self.propertyListBarChart.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
    self.propertyListBarChart.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, -16.0f);

    // 5 - Set up plot space
    //NSNumber *topValue = (NSNumber *)[[[DataStore sharedStore] valuesForBars] objectAtIndex:0];

    //X-Axis will contain Amount and Y-Axis acutally there is nothing to plot.

    CGFloat xMin = 0.0f;
    CGFloat xMax = 15000000.0f;
    CGFloat yMin = 0.0f;
    CGFloat yMax = 7.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) self.propertyListBarChart.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xMin) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xMax)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(yMin) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(yMax)];
}

- (void)configurePropertyPlot
{
    // 1 - Set up Bar plot.
    self.propertyBarPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor] horizontalBars:NO];
    self.propertyBarPlot.identifier = kTopWellsBarPlot;
    [self.propertyBarPlot setBarsAreHorizontal:YES];

    // 3 - Add plots to graph
    CPTGraph *graph = self.propertyListBarChart;
    self.propertyBarPlot.dataSource = (id)self;
    self.propertyBarPlot.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromDouble(4.0f);
    //self.propertyBarPlot.lineStyle = barLineStyle;
    [self.propertyListBarChart addPlot:self.propertyBarPlot toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];
}

-(void)configurePropertyPlotAxes
{
    // 1 - Configure styles
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 3.0f;
    //axisLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blueColor];

    // 2 - Get the graph's axis set
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.topWellsGraphHostingView.hostedGraph.axisSet;

    // 3 - Configure the x-axis
    axisSet.xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions;
    axisSet.xAxis.title = @"Amount";
    axisSet.xAxis.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.titleOffset = 10.0f;
    axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;

    // 4 - Configure the y-axis
    axisSet.yAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions;
    axisSet.yAxis.title = @"Top 5";
    axisSet.yAxis.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.titleOffset = 5.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - CPTPlotDataSource methods
- (NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
    NSLog(@"Names Array: %@",[[DataStore sharedStore] namesForBars]);
    NSLog(@"Values Array: %@",[[DataStore sharedStore] valuesForBars]);
    NSLog(@"Formatted Values Array: %@",[[DataStore sharedStore] formattedValuesForBars]);

    //return [[[DataStore sharedStore] namesForBars] count];
    return [[self plotDataValues] count];
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSNumber *num = nil;

    if ((fieldEnum == 1 || fieldEnum == 0 || fieldEnum == 2) && (index < [[[DataStore sharedStore] valuesForBars] count]))
    {
        float value = 0.00f;

        if ([plot isKindOfClass:[CPTBarPlot class]])
        {
            NSString *plotIdentifier = (NSString *)plot.identifier;

            if ([plotIdentifier isEqualToString:kTopWellsBarPlot])
            {
                value = [[[self plotDataValues] objectAtIndex:index] doubleValue];
            }
        }

        num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:value];
    }
    return num;
}
```

Can somebody tell me is there an issue in the implementation. The hosting view is added to the Xib.

Answer (score 3):

1. The datasource should check the plot field using the predefined constants (`CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation`, `CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip`, and `CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase`) rather than using "magic" numbers.
2. Most bar plots will require at least a location and a tip value for each bar. Be sure the datasource returns the correct value for each field.
3. The `length` of a plot range should be `max - min`, not `max`. In this case, it doesn't matter since the `min` value is zero, but it will matter in other cases.

There are many examples of bar plots in the Core Plot example apps. The *Plot Gallery* app is a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I tried the fieldEnum constants initially and it did not work that is why I switched to manual numbering. I will check in the sample apps.